# Extracting elements from a 1D array. Getting error invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have to extract elements from a 1D array and write a file.

```
import numpy as np
k0 =78
tpts = 10
x_mirror = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
alpha = -3
x_start = 3
u0 = []
for p in range(0,tpts):                              #initial condition at t = 0
    ts =  ((np.exp(alpha*((x_mirror[p]-x_start)**2))*(np.cos(k0*(x_mirror[p]-x_start)))))
    u0.append(ts)
u0_array = np.array(u0)[np.newaxis]
u0_array_transpose = np.transpose(u0_array)
matrix_A = np.zeros((tpts,tpts))  
matrix_A[tpts-1][tpts-1] = 56  
matrixC = matrix_A @ u0_array_transpose
matrixC2 = matrix_A @ u0
u_pre = np.array(np.zeros(tpts))
print(u0_array)
```

In this I want to extract suppose elements of u0_array separately. I get my u0_array as `[[ 2.89793185e-06 -4.27075012e-02  1.00000000e+00 -4.27075012e-02 2.89793185e-06  9.14080657e-14 -7.91091805e-22  2.42062877e-33 -1.24204313e-47  1.15841796e-64]]`. This is just for example. How can I get different elements of u0_array? By using u0[][], I am getting error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `u0_array.flatten()` ... `u0_list = u0_array.tolist()` ... From here, you can access all the different elements as list and using only 1 index (If that's what you are asking for)

Comment: Is there any other method to get elements without converting it into list using `.flatten`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u0_array` is an array that contains an array of floats. To index an individual element, use `u0_array[0][(index to access)]`. You can also use `.flatten()`, as the comment states.

Comment: using `u0_array[0][(index to access)]` I am getting an error as `list index out of range`

Comment: What index are you trying to access?

Comment: I tried getting [0][1], [0][2] etc...but got errors

Comment: Weird, I'm able to access `[0][1]` just fine (`-0.04270750124955338`). Are you sure you haven't made any other changes to the code since you've posted?

Comment: Ok that was my fault, I had put brackets. Thanks a lot for the help. Sorry for inconvenience